# Возможно ли папку на удаленном сервере (Ubuntu 20.x) в Google Cloud подмонтировать как сетевой диск в Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, google-cloud

Возможно ли папку на удаленном сервере (Ubuntu 20.x) в Google Cloud подмонтировать как сетевой диск в Windows 10? Если да, то как?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, но результат по производительности может вас не обрадовать.

А так, вешаете VPN (подойдет openVPN) на удаленный сервер и далее работаете с вашей удаленной папкой по протоколу SMB, как обычно.

VPN здесь нужен для решения двух проблем:

1. Протокол SMB никак не шифрует передаваемые данные, так что их смогут перехватить или изменить по дороге
2. Частенько в SMB находят дыры огромных размеров, через которые на уязвимий компьютер можно залить и исполнить вредоносный код. [EthernalBlue](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/EternalBlue), например.

Comment: Если отбросить производительность, то как подключиться? Мне нужноо периодически править текстовые файлы на удаленном сервере. Пытался подключиться и через Visual Studio Code и через ssh-win. Проблема с аутентифкацией и как понимаю с ssh ключами. Не понимаю как правильно их настроить для работы с google cloud instance